# Location of anaconda base environment moved after creating a new environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

Starting from conda environment as following:

```
(base) C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3>conda info -e
#conda environments:
base                  *  C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3
```

I used the following code to create a new anaconda environment,

```
(base) C:\Windows\System32>conda create -n my_env1 anaconda
```

Then I got

```
(base) C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3>conda info -e
#conda environments:
                         C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3
base                  *  C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\envs\my_env1
```

Note that the location of base environment moved, and the previous base environment doesn't have any name anymore.

If I look up the information of new environment, its name is base, not my_env1. Why is that? How to fix this?

```
(base) C:\Windows\System32>conda activate my_env1
(my_env1) C:\Windows\System32>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\envs\my_env1
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\NAME\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\NAME\.condarc
          conda version : 22.11.1
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.15.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=11.7=0
                          __win=0=0
       base environment : C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\envs\my_env1  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\envs\my_env1\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\envs\my_env1\pkgs
                          C:\Users\NAME\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\envs\my_env1\envs
                          C:\Users\NAME\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/22.11.1 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22621
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Is this a bug, as everything else works fine, except that "active environment" tag is "base" in my_env1 environment?

Comment: As per duplicate, remove `conda` from the other environment. The `conda` package should only be installed in the **base**.